# SNS publishing to multiple EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

when I try to subscribe an http endpoint from an EC2 instance to an SNS topic, I get the following message:

"Not authorized to subscribe internal endpoints"

Is there any workaround for this?
What is the best way to implement a pub/sub mechanism in AWS?

Comment: Hello, did you find any workaround ? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This means you have used the private IP instead of the public IP.

The easiest way to solve this is to log in to the AWS Console for EC2 (https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2).  Then click on the instance and you can see it has both a public and a private DNS.  You want to use the public one.

To get this information programmatically from an instance you can do this on the instance: `curl -s http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/meta-data/public-hostname`.  This is documented here:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html

Comment: thanks for your help, the thing is, this instance is a private instance, I wanted to use SNS as a pub/sub mechanism to exchange messages between my private instances but I guess this is not possible.

Comment: @smnbss did you ever solve this in any other way? was hoping to do the same thing.

Comment: would Kinesis be able to do this?